# generate sha256 hash for a string in objective C equivalent to C# without using key

Tags: c#, objective-c, hash, sha256

In c# I am doing

```
 HashAlgorithm hash=SHA256.create();
    string myHash = Convert.ToBase64String( hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello")));
```

and in objective c I am doing

```
const unsigned char arr[32];
        CC_SHA256([@"hello" UTF8String], 32, &arr);
        NSMutableData *HM = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)arr length:32];
        NSLog(@"macHah  %@",[HM base64EncodingWithLineLength:0]);
```

but both of them generates different hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following :

```
- (NSData *)sha256:(NSData *)data
{
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    if ( CC_SHA256([data bytes], [data length], hash) )
    {
        NSData *hashData = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        return hashData;
    }
    return nil;
}
```